# Procesar solo un mensaje a la vez en Active MQ

Tags: java, socket, activemq

Tengo un proceso en Java que utiliza ActimeMQ, los mensajes encolados son procesador por Java y se envían a un socket. El problema es que activeMQ procesa de forma asíncrona varios mensajes a la vez, y los envía en el socket, provocando que al escuchar el socket se reciban los mensajes en distinto orden que el enviado.
Es posible forzar a que ActiveMQ mantenga los mensajes en cola si aún mantiene un mensaje que no ha sido "dequeued"?, esto con la intención de que se procese solamente un mensaje a la vez en el socket, en el orden que se reciben.

Answer (score 0):

Luego de más pruebas, comprendí que por defecto ActiveMQ encola los mensajes. La causa del problema que tenía, era otro proceso que no pasaba por una cola.